# Is a prime submodel of a module over dedkind domain is maximal?

Tags: modules, maximal-and-prime-ideals, dedekind-domain

Let be $R$ a Dedekind domain, $M$ a $R$-module and $P$ a prime submodule (if $rm\in P$, then $m\in P$ or $r\in (P:M)$ for every $r\in R$ and $m\in M$). Is $P$ is a maximal submodule of $M$?

Comment: What is $(P:M)$?

Comment: $(P:M)=\{r\in R\  :\  rM\subseteq P\}$